# Simulating Google app engine maintenance period in development environment

Tags: google-app-engine

During scheduled maintenance period outages, the high replication datastore will work normally, but memcache will not be available.

Is there a way this scenario can be simulated in local development environment?

More specifically, can we run dev_appserver.py with memcache disabled to test the maintenance period behavior?

As of now, I go to development console and flush out the memcache after every request, to get a rough idea of how the app behaves during server maintenance.  I am hoping there must be some better way to test this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Create an api post call hook that will return `None` for memcache get requests. Refer to the [official docs for creating an api post call hook](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/hooks).